# How can I get a date from my FormControl from a DatePicker in Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i get a date from my FormControl from a DatePicker in Angular Material

HTML:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp_" formControlName="fechaSolicitud" 
        (dateChange)="showDate()">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="dp_"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dp_></mat-datepicker>
```

TS:

```
PayFormGroup=new FormGroup({
...
fechaSolicitud: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
...
})

showDate(){
console.log(this.PayFormGroup.get('fechaSolicitud')?.value)
}
```

I get this result but i want the date
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C517o.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `Moment` object. This means your date-picker (library) is configured in a way that it works with [the moment library](https://momentjs.com/) and returns you Moment objects accordingly. You can easily change the returned result to a date string using the following line:

```
const date: string = value.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Or alternatively [to the native Javascript Date class](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) using the following line:

```
const date: Date = value.toDate();
```

Where `value` is the `Moment` object you showed in your screenshot.

For alternative formats I will refer to [the official Moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs).